# Xamarin Forms Prism : Issue with Deeplinking, navigating to another tab and opening a page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

In my xamarin forms application,
I have a tabbed page and on a button click event of Tab1 I want to open a page on a different tab say Tab2. For that I'm using the following code:

**VIEWMODEL** -- **Not Working**

```
      private async Task NavigatePage()
        {
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { 
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage?selectedTab=Tab2Page/TargetPage"); 
        });
}//This returns a blank page
```

**Works**

```
    private async Task TryNavigating()
    {
          Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
                { 
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/MainPage?selectedTab=Tab2Page/TargetPage"); 
                });
    }
```

`NavigatePage()` opens the selected tab(`Tab2Page`) but unable to navigate to `TargetPage` but instead displays white screen, where as  `TryNavigating()` opens the selected tab and goes to `Tab2Page` but if you navigate back you will see extra navigation bar on top of selected tab which I don't want to display.

Can anyone please help? Am i not using the navigation service the right way or is there issue with the way I'm navigating?

Comment: If you want to navigate to one page in TabPage, you can take a look the TabPage with NavigationPage [https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/]

Comment: It is regular tab navigation. My question is when you are already on one tab and when you click on a button on that tab you have to open new page on different tab.